# Submitting data to Firestore from formik in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, formik, formik-material-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to submit form data to firestore from a formik form in a react app.

I've used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/codefully-io/react-forms-validation-with-formik-and-material-ui-1adf0c1cae5c) to try to learn how to make the form and then tried to add the firebase form submission to the submit handler.

The form has:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { Link  } from 'react-router-dom';
    import firebase from '../../../../firebase';
//  import firestore from '../../../../firebase';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
    import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
    import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
    import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
    import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
    // import axios from 'axios';
    import {
      Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage,
    } from 'formik';
    import * as Yup from 'yup';
    // import { DisplayFormikState } from './formikHelper';
    
    const styles = {
    
    };
    




function Contact(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isSubmitionCompleted, setSubmitionCompleted] = useState(false);
  
  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setSubmitionCompleted(false);
    setOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Link
            // component="button"
            className="footerlinks"
            onClick={handleClickOpen}
        >
            Contact
        </Link>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
      >
        {!isSubmitionCompleted &&
          <React.Fragment>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Contact Us</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText>
                Thanks for your interest.
              </DialogContentText>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', name: '', comment: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                   setSubmitting(true);
                   firebase.firestore.collection("contact").doc.set({
                    name: "name",
                    email: "email",
                    comment: "comment"
                })
                //   axios.post(contactFormEndpoint,
                //     values,
                //     {
                //       headers: {
                //         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                //         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                //       }
                //     },
                  .then(() => {
                    setSubmitionCompleted(true);
                  });
                }}

                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                  email: Yup.string()
                    .email()
                    .required('Required'),
                  name: Yup.string()
                    .required('Required'),
                  comment: Yup.string()
                    .required('Required'),
                })}
              >
                {(props) => {
                  const {
                    values,
                    touched,
                    errors,
                    dirty,
                    isSubmitting,
                    handleChange,
                    handleBlur,
                    handleSubmit,
                    handleReset,
                  } = props;
                  return (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <TextField
                        label="Name"
                        name="name"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={values.name}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        helperText={(errors.name && touched.name) && errors.name}
                        margin="normal"
                        style={{ width: "100%"}}
                      />

                      <TextField
                        error={errors.email && touched.email}
                        label="Email"
                        name="email"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={values.email}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        helperText={(errors.email && touched.email) && errors.email}
                        margin="normal"
                        style={{ width: "100%"}}
                      />

                      <TextField
                        label="Let us know how we can help"
                        name="comment"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        multiline
                        rows={4}
                        value={values.comment}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        helperText={(errors.comment && touched.comment) && errors.comment}
                        margin="normal"
                        style={{ width: "100%"}}
                      />
                      <DialogActions>
                        <Button
                          type="button"
                          className="outline"
                          onClick={handleReset}
                          disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting}
                        >
                          Reset
                        </Button>
                        <Button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                          Submit
                        </Button>
                        {/* <DisplayFormikState {...props} /> */}
                      </DialogActions>
                    </form>
                  );
                }}
              </Formik>
            </DialogContent>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
        {isSubmitionCompleted &&
          <React.Fragment>
            <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Thanks!</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
              <DialogContentText>
                Thanks
              </DialogContentText>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  className="outline"
                  onClick={handleClose}
                >
                  Back to app
                  </Button>
                {/* <DisplayFormikState {...props} /> */}
              </DialogActions>
            </DialogContent>
          </React.Fragment>}
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Contact);
```

The firestore config file has:

When I try this, I get a warning in the console when I press submit (no error messages and the form just hangs with data that I entered in the form.

> instrument.ts:129 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from
> submitForm() TypeError:
> *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.default.firestore.collection is not a function

Note, I've dried both .doc.set and .doc.add in the firestore method - neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it eventually -the doc has to be doc()

Comment: please, consider marking your answer as accepted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer